# Hadoop Knox using WebHCat is slower than previous

Tags: hadoop, hcatalog, knox-gateway

I am trying to use Knox for my MapReduce job. Previously, I didn't use Knox, the MapReduce job takes 35s.

But after using Knox, I see an additional job - TempletonControllerJob executes first, and it will start my original MapReduce job, which actually takes more time - about 1min 20s!

I understand that the MapReduce job is now a sub-job of TempletonControllerJob.

- But how can I make it faster?
- Why does the TempletonControllerJob take so long?

Answer (score 0):

That is an interesting observation and question. Unfortunately, this is a question for the Apache Hive project and Templeton/WebHCat rather than Apache Knox. Knox is only proxying the WebHCat API for submitting jobs. Wish I could be of more help.